# Value of buttons to be changed with click of next and prev

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Button next and prev not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494574/button-next-and-prev-not-working)

I have 5 buttons in my layout and on the next button i want to change the text of the button which is from a arraylist. how could i implement this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout style="@style/verticallayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_weight=".16"
            android:text="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/verticallayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b2"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_weight=".16"
            android:text="2 />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/verticallayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b3"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_weight=".16"
            android:text="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/verticallayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_weight=".16"
            android:text="4" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout style="@style/verticallayout" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b5"
            style="@style/buttons"
            android:layout_weight=".16"
            android:text="5" />
    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="Prev" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:text="Next" />
</LinearLayout>
```

my java class::
here count is the static variable.

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    String a=null;
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.left:


        if( count==0)
            prev.setEnabled(false);
        else{
             count--;

        }
        break;
    case R.id.right:
        if( count>5)
            next.setEnabled(false);
        else{
             count++;

        }
        break;
    case R.id.b1:

            a=(( count*0)+0)+"";
            bb1.setText(a);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.b2:

            a= (( count*0)+1)+"";
            bb2.setText(a);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.b3:

            a= (( count*0)+2)+"";
            bb3.setText(a);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.b4:

            a= ((count*0)+3)+"";
            bb4.setText(a);
        }
        break;
    case R.id.b5:

            a= ((count*0)+4)+"";
            bb5.setText(a);
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

i want the button text to be changed by the value of count. but the values are not changing.
my doubt is that is there a need to refresh the acctivity after every click of next and prev

Comment: i want to change the texxt value of b1,2,3,4,5 based on the count.. like if once next is clicked then the values shd b 5,6,7,8 respectively and on prev it shd b decremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, you are trying to change the Text of the Buttons in the Click Event of their self.

So, when you click next or prev, the text in the buttons won't change(only count changes). They only change(actually updated with latest count values) when you click on them(b1,2,3,4,5).

So, to get what you required do this:

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
String a=null;
switch(arg0.getId()){
case R.id.left:


    if( count==0)
        prev.setEnabled(false);
    else{
         count--;
         //You want to change the text(count) of button1,2,3,4,5 when you click prev.
         //So, do that here

bb1.setText("" + count);
bb2.setText("" + count);
bb3.setText("" + count);
bb4.setText("" + count);
bb5.setText("" + count);

         //Similarly on next clicked

    break;
case R.id.right:
    if( count>5)
        next.setEnabled(false);
    else{
         count++;
bb1.setText("" + count);
bb2.setText("" + count);
bb3.setText("" + count);
bb4.setText("" + count);
bb5.setText("" + count);

    break;
case R.id.b1:
        //here don't change any text, just check the text value and call the respective answer
       if(bb1.getText == "5"){
          //call answer5 etc..,
          }

          //do the same with other buttons b2,3,4,5
    break;
case R.id.b2:

        a= (( count*0)+1)+"";
        bb2.setText(a);

    break;
case R.id.b3:

        a= (( count*0)+2)+"";
        bb3.setText(a);

    break;
case R.id.b4:

        a= ((count*0)+3)+"";
        bb4.setText(a);

    break;
case R.id.b5:

        a= ((count*0)+4)+"";
        bb5.setText(a);

    break;

}
```

}

by which you are changing the text of the buttons on click of the next and prev buttons

Comment: then how do i give the onclick functionality of those buttons available?

Comment: Let me clarify 1 thing. You want to change the text of b1,2,3,4,5 when you click on next or prev buttons right? Then you must implement that text change in the onClick of next and prev buttons but not in the onClick of b1,2,3,4,5. After that if you want to give the onClick functionality to b1,2,3,4,5 add those functionality in the onClick of b1,2,3,4,5 which are the last 5 cases in your switch block

Comment: From your code onClick of b1,2,3,4,5 you are trying to change the text but nothing else. Which should have been in onClick of next and prev buttons

Comment: i have few more functionality wich is working in the b12345. based on the text the functionality changes out of the button. if text is 8 then 8th answer is shown on click in button click. so i want the text and onclick in same place.

Comment: You said your buttons text is not changing. So, now click next--> text of b1,2,3,4,5 wont change. Now click any of b1,2,3,4,5--> this time the text of the clicked button changes. Thats because you implemented the text change in b1,2,3,4,5. Let me add the complete code with explanation.

Comment: Check the code in the edited answer

Comment: thanks a lot.. got the solution wanted from this..

Answer (score 0):

are you missing this code? :

```
Button Button1= (button)findviewbyid(R.id.right);
Button1.setonclicklistener(this);
```

Comment: i have it above the onclick function.. i just added the onclik functionality

Answer (score 0):

In your onClick() method the logic is not correct..only two cases required..

When you pressing next or previous button you can change the text of the remaing five buttons

Thats solved....

Comment: i also have the button functionality out there for them. else i would have gone with text view if its jst the matter of chnging text..